# Smallest (less internal code), up-to-spec JSON parser in Java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have seen there are many JSON parsers in Java. Some target speed, some target accuracy, some target flexibility (streaming, buffering, etc). Some have use special subclasses of the collections api instead of using the ones that are already there. That seems bloated to me.

So I would like to know, which one(s) tackle the job of string to object conversion in the shortest/simplest manner? (as in, less code)

**Edit:** I am sorry I was not clear. What I mean is the smallest parser. So if one parser was 600 lines and the other was 400 lines. I don't care which is faster so much as which is easier to understand. This is not to be confused with how many lines it takes to invoke the parser. I expect almost all would be just a few lines of code and if I have to add a convenience method that is OK.

Purpose is more of an educational thing, how is it done, and the wish to use APIs where it is easy to see how it works.

Comment: Do you mean which API requires you to write the least code to convert JSON to objects or which uses the least code internally (i.e. small file size for the dependency)?

Comment: Least code internally. Good catch. I wish I was here 55 minutes ago, because now the only answers are to a different, already asked, more common, not what I am looking for question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two. Jackson or Gson. I'll add some examples.

[GSON](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Long one = gson.fromJson("1", Long.class);
```

[Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // can reuse, share globally
User user = mapper.readValue(new File("user.json"), User.class);
```

Jackson is a little faster so its up to you what you want.

Comment: Then I guess this is what you are looking for http://json.org/java/ it is small and few classes only?

Answer (score 3):

What about http://code.google.com/p/json-smart/? It's very small, apparently. Seems to be up to date.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) is my preference for this. All you have to do is make a class with a structure that matches a JSON object and converting JSON can be as simple as:

```
Foo foo = new Gson().fromJson(json, Foo.class);
```

If there's something more complex you need to do, you only need to add some field annotations or write a custom serializer/deserializer (which is pretty easy) and register it once. Actually converting JSON to objects is always just a matter of calling `gson.fromJson(...)`.

Comment: I didn't know about Google Gson. It's very nice :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a really minimal JSON parser, you should have a look at these:

- [JSON.simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)
- [minimal-json](https://github.com/ralfstx/minimal-json)

Both are complete JSON implementations that consist of only a dozen Java classes.

Comment: That's about 11 too much!

Answer (score 1):

[My parser](http://tech.dolhub.com/code/JsonParser) is a **single class**, and **740 lines** after stripping comments; it's efficient, fully functional and has a number of options for parsing "human readable" JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Let me mention the solution at https://github.com/KasparNagu/plain-java-json using 107 lines for the parser class.

Yet of course, if you plan to use it, you're way better off with one of the proven implementations mentioned above.

Comment: Having a quick look at the code, this implementation looks very inefficient.